# check history along with dates for queries in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, linux

I am running `PostgreSQL` on my Linux terminal and If we do select `pg_backend_pid();` it gives `pid` for specific session.

Below gives us only the last query executed

```
select pid,
       usename as username,
       datname as database_name,
       query,
       application_name,
       backend_start,
       state,
       state_change
from pg_stat_activity
where pid = 'your-pid';
```

but looks like this `\s` gives us all the history of query but not with dates. can we get dates along with them

and if we do save output to a filename where does it gets stored on `Linux` server?

```
\s filename
```

Kindly suggest if there are more specific way, actually I am looking for the queries executed on particular date.

Comment: The history you see with `\s` is managed by the `psql` _client_  not by the server.

Comment: okee.. I quit PostgreSQL and could see that file at my local Linux server :-) but its doesn't have the dates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't remember the times when queries are run.

If you need that information, set `log_statement = 'all'` and include `%m` in `log_line_prefix`. Then the queries and their time are written to the log file.

Comment: Thanks and where we can edit this.. in the configuration files..

Comment: Yes; change `postgresql.conf` and reload.

Comment: And regardless of how many time we logged in and ran commands.. \s will capture all the previous query's.. isn't ?

Comment: If possible can you also update info regarding conf file... Will be helpful for others or new comer like me. Thanks

Comment: There are several ways to change the configuration, all documented, so I see no worth in that. `\s` is a `psql` tool to access the history *on the client*.